# How do I split a vector layer into separate grid layers?

Tags: splitting, vector-grid

I need to split a vector layer into 1km x 1km squares so I can carry out some calculations for these individual areas.

Is there a feature to do this?

Comment: @user13541, What GIS applications do you have to use for your task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using ArcGIS, one way to go about this is to create a 1 X 1 KM [Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) grid followed by using the [Split](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000) tool.

[image]

The general workflow/model looks like this:

[image]